# How to use jQuery to convert text to email links

Tags: jquery, email, html-table

I have an HTML table with one column being email addresses; spambot issues aside, I'd like to convert each `<td>` element in this column to a mailto: link.

Here's what I've got:

```
$("table.data tbody tr td:last").each(function() {
    var email = $(this).val();
    $(this).html('<a href="mailto:' + email + '">' + email + '</a>');
});
```

And this is the table (sample):

```
<tr>
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td>Shmoe</td>
    <td>example@example.net</td>
</tr>
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your jquery selector is wrong.

When you do **'table.data tbody tr td:last'** it will only select the last cell of the last row.

What you need to do is something like:

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {
        //For each row...
        $('table.data tbody tr').each(
            function()
            {  
                //...find the last cell.
                var lastCell = $(this).find('td:last');
                $(lastCell).html('<a href="mailto:' + $(lastCell).text() + '">' + $(lastCell).text() + '</a>');
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/umiza
Code: http://jsbin.com/umiza/edit

Answer (score 1):

You should use **.text()** instead of **.val()**:

```
$("table.data tbody tr td:last").each(function() {
    var email = $(this).text();
    $(this).html('<a href="mailto:' + email + '">' + email + '</a>');
});
```